# while loop and boolean

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

not understanding how to get the loop to stop and continue/repeat
also, not understanding how to get second part of boolean to work

```
monthly_investment = float(input("Enter monthly investment:\t"))
while monthly_investment < 1:
    print("Entry must be greater than 0")

yearly_interest_rate = float(input("Enter yearly interest rate:\t"))
while yearly_interest_rate < 1 and yearly_interest_rate < 16:
    print("Entry must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 15" )
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Comment: i understand the loop just not how to go back if the value is o

Comment: Go back to where? If you want to do something based on a condition, use if statements

Comment: that makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nimkora,

You just need to add another assignment statement at the end of while loop so that, once, user enter a valid input, program can break out of the while loop.

```
monthly_investment = float(input("Enter monthly investment:\t"))
while monthly_investment < 1:
    print("Entry must be greater than 0")
    monthly_investment = float(input("Enter monthly investment:\t"))

yearly_interest_rate = float(input("Enter yearly interest rate:\t"))
while yearly_interest_rate < 1 and yearly_interest_rate < 16:
    print("Entry must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 15" )
    yearly_interest_rate = float(input("Enter yearly interest rate:\t"))
```